# building a jstree based on json data

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am attempting to use json data to build a jstree as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {  

   $("#left").jstree({   

         "json_data" : {  

             "ajax" : {

                 "url": "http://192.168.101.2/img/jstree.json",  

                 "data" : function (n) {   

                     return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };   
                     }  
                 }  
            },  
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]  
        });  
     });
});
```

my tree is not building, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: no error, I keep getting an infinite loading image.

Comment: Do you have an `id` in your json data?

Comment: If you remove `http://192.168.101.2` leaving `/img/jstree.json` would it still be hitting the same json file? ( in other words, is this json file on the same domain, or a different domain )

Comment: my goal is to call the json file with an http from another ip. I tested this having local json file, that is not working either.

Comment: When you do `console.log()` on json data then does it return any json data?

Comment: console.log(data) returns nothing

Comment: So you are not getting json data. It means there is some problem with the url you are giving.

Comment: no, the file is there. I just tried it with having the file locally that does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

You have to use one of these `$().ready(function() {})` or `$(function() {})`. These both have same meaning.

```
$(function () {  

     $("#left").jstree({   

         "json_data" : {  

             "ajax" : {

                 "url": "http://192.168.101.2/img/jstree.json",  

                 "data" : function (n) {   

                     return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };   
                 }  
             }  
        },  
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]  
   });  
});
```

Comment: that did not work. Still getting the loading image on my left div.

Comment: Your current code does not help us a lot. We need some more code to help you out.